# Is the JabbR codebase documented anywhere?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, jabbr

Is the JabbR source documented anywhere? I'm looking at integrating it into a project and wondered if the architecture and extensibility points are explained?

Comment: There's nothing external to GIT that I'm aware of. If you're looking for a turnkey solution, though, you might check out http://www.chatjs.net/.

Answer (score 0):

It's documented in source code :) https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR

Comment: Cannot find any documentation anywhere.